# Python - "Autopassing" a try in all my methods

Tags: python-3.x

I have some methods:

```
def plus(a, b):
    res = (a + b)
    return res
def by(a, b):
    res = (a * b)
    return res
def split(a, b):
    res = (a / b)
    return res
def takeaway(a, b):
    res = (a - b)
    return res
```

I want to know if there is a way I could take that methods as:

```
def plus(a, b):
    try:
        res = (a + b)
        return res
    except:
        return False
def by(a, b):
    try:
        res = (a * b)
        return res
    except:
        return False
def split(a, b):
    try:
        res = (a / b)
        return res
    except:
        return False
def takeaway(a, b):
    try:
        res = (a - b)
        return res
    except:
        return False
```

Without being explicit, so I am working on Web Server App, if there is a *raise* the app stops, and I just want to log every error on a file, but keep the app working.

I though about decorators but those are methods that executes before the others (plus, by, split, takeaway...)

So I don't know what I have to do, I need to globally catch raises, to prevent app stop. :(

Surely I'm not giving a good explanation but I try my best. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a decorator exactly because they are executed *before* (even *instead of*) the decorated function.

For example:

```
def catch_exception(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            return False
    return wrapper
```

And then just decorate all the functions you want.

Comment: I will test :) Thank you